# Combining Elements of multiple arrays and applying a loop to search for the combined elements

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

Please forgive me as im not a coder by default i do this as a hobby by picking up small projects and trying to solve them as best i can.

I have a binary file that i convert to Hex with Bit Converter, i then output this to a Multiline Textbox, i then remove null data by searching the text for 00-00-00-00-E (which is the 1st record entry) using:

```
                //remove the Null Data at file Entry
                int pos = hexData.IndexOf("00-00-00-00-E");
                if (pos >= 0)
                {
                    string hexData2 = hexData.Remove(0, pos);

                    //Remove dashes
                    textBox1.Text = hexData2.Replace("-", "");
                }
```

once ive done this i then split the lines by searching:

```
                int recordNumber = 0;
                int i = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("0000E"); // missing 1st 2 bytes from records as this was the only way i could split the lines
                do
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("0000E", "Record " + recordNumber++ + ", E");
                    recordNumber++;
                }
                while (i >= 0);
```

i then put lines into a list and remove the 1st 3 lines which leaves me with record 1 on wards (but with the byte data broken as the 1st 2 record  bytes are on the previous line)

what i want to do is generate strings of hex data from 4 arrays, i was attempting to take a element from each array to build the string i.e:

`array1 {00} + array2 {00} + array3 {00} +array4 {00} = outputString {00000000}`

i was looking to do this and then increment it starting from byte array 1 and cycling through

Example:

```
00000000
01000000
02000000
03000000
FF000000
00010000
01010000
02010000
04CA0100
FF000100
```

and so forth

intended to use of these arrays

```
string[] byteData = { "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "0A", "0B", "0C", "0D", "0E", "0F", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F",
                       "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E", "3F",
                       "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "5E", "5F",
                       "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "6E", "6F", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "7A", "7B", "7C", "7D", "7E", "7F",
                       "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "8A", "8B", "8C", "8D", "8E", "8F", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "9A", "9B", "9C", "9D", "9E", "9F",
                       "A0", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "B0", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF",
                       "C0", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD", "CE", "CF", "D0", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD", "DE", "DF",
                       "E0", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", "EE", "EF", "F0", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "FA", "FB", "FC", "FD", "FE", "FF" };
```

I tried to use .Union but this removes duplicates so I only ended up with 1 data from 1 array and 1 set of characters "00".

once i have got this resolved i wanted to put this in to a loop to search some text file/text box so i could identify potential matches  and then replace it with "Record {0}", record" and have each record an incrementing number or some thing like that

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? It seems actually that you could generate the arrays using a loop and incrementing the iteration variable. you can use `Int.ToString("X2");` method to generated the appropriate hex representation of the integer

Comment: The gist of it is as follows:
I have a binary file that im converting  to hex using bitconverter i then out put this to a multiline textbox, this contains records (in hex) that i want to split into individual lines and replace 4 bytes with Record {number}.

Comment: Try following :             uint[] input = { 0x00000000, 0x01000000, 0x02000000, 0x03000000, 0xFF000000, 0x00010000, 0x01010000, 0x02010000, 0x04CA0100, 0xFF000100 };
            string output = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", input.SelectMany(x => new string[] { (x >> 24).ToString("X2"), ((x >> 16) & 0xFF).ToString("X2"), ((x >> 8) & 0xFF).ToString("X2"), (x & 0xFF).ToString("X2") }).ToList()) + "\"";

Comment: i need to account for every potential byte sequence, this is basically 256*256*256*256 (4,294,967,296 -- potential ouputs which is why i was looking to create some loop to do it) i know its not likely that i will ever hit that number of records in theory i really only need the 1st 2 bytes as thats 65536, may need to dip into 00,01,02 on byte 3 at a push

Comment: Use a list :             List<string> output = new List<string>();
            for (uint i = 0; i <= 0xFFFF; i++)
            {
                output.Add(((i >> 8) & 0xFF).ToString("X2"));
                output.Add((i & 0xFF).ToString("X2"));
            }

Comment: @jdweng,  works but bytes are wrong way round, does 000001, 000002. can we flip it big endian/little  endian??

Comment: Change the order of the two output statements.

Comment: @jdweng, I ended up having to tweak the stuff you gave me.                for (uint i = 0; i <= 0xFFFF; i++)
                {
                    // add hex value to list
                    output.Add(((i) & 0xFFFF).ToString("X4"));
                }

I then used another loop to add the 0000 or 0100 to the end of each result as it was producing too many and severely slowing it down